# Analysis of numbers of the form $(2^p-1)^2$ where p is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm interested in numbers of the form $(M_p)^2$ where p is prime, where $M_p$ is the Mersenne number of index p (i.e. $M_p = 2^p-1$). To be clear, I don’t mean only the Mersenne primes, but all Mersenne numbers whose index is prime. I haven’t found much on the internet about this sequence - just an OEIS sequence which just lists the definition http://oeis.org/A174744.

In particular, the totient ($\phi$) is $\phi((M_p)^2) = \phi(M_p)*M_p$. Mostly the order of a number b in $(M_p)^2$ has $M_p$ as a divisor, the order being the smallest power o with $b^o = 1\mod (M_p)^2$. In other words there are very few numbers that have:

$$b^{\phi(M_p)} = 1 \mod (M_p)^2 \text{ with } (b < M_p \text{ and } b \text{ coprime to } M_p)$$

In checking primes up to 31, and $b < M_p$, $b$ coprime to $M_p$, there are 5 such combinations. These are:

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
p& b  \\ \hline
7&38\\ \hline
7&62\\ \hline
13&6805\\ \hline
19&332924\\ \hline
31&2066996122\\ \hline
\end{array}

Note in all these cases $M_p$ is prime and I also noticed that $b^{\phi(M_p)/p} = 2^n + n*2^n*(\phi(M_p)/p) * M_p + k M_p^2$.

Specifically I’m looking to establish that for a given b there is a constraint on the primes p - either that there is at most one such p or a finite number of primes where $b^{\phi(M_p)} = 1 \mod (M_p)^2$ with $b < M_p$ and b coprime to $M_p$. I’ve attempted various approaches to show this but to no avail, including Fermat's Little Theorem, the fact that the various $M_p$ are coprime to each other, the fact that p divides $\phi(M_p)$, and the unproved assertion that I noted in the prior paragraph.

I would appreciate if anyone has any suggestions for other approaches to my question. And if nothing else, if anyone knew of any papers that analyzed number of the form $M_p^2$, that would also be of interest.

Comment: Note that to determine the totient function of some number we have to factor it. The factorizations of $M_p$ are however complete upto an astonishing high level.